# How to figure out weekly start date

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures

I have a Stored Function that it supposed to figure out my week start date for payroll. Which is "Thursday"  However my stored procedure always gets my start date as "Friday"  What is wrong with my declare and set functions?  I want my StartWeekDay to be "Thursday"... "lStartday" is set to "5" in the account table My code is below:

```
DECLARE @StartWeekDay int 
SET @StartWeekDay = (Select lStartDay From Account Where lLocationID = 1)

DECLARE @CurrentDate DateTime 
SET @CurrentDate = GetDate()
DECLARE @CurrentWeekDay int
SET @CurrentWeekDay = DATEPART(dw,@CurrentDate)

DECLARE @Diff int
SET @Diff = @StartWeekDay - @CurrentWeekDay

SET @Diff = Case When @Diff > 0 Then -6 When @Diff = 0 Then 0 Else @Diff End

--
 DECLARE @DaysToStart int
 SET @DaysToStart = (DatePart(dw,@CurrentDate) - @StartWeekDay)
 IF @DaysToStart <= .1 
  BEGIN
    SET @DaysToStart = @DaysToStart + 7 
  END

 DECLARE @myStartWeekDate DateTime
 --SET @myStartWeekDate = dbo.DateOnly(DATEADD(d,@Diff,@CurrentDate))
 SET @myStartWeekDate =  Convert(nvarchar,DateAdd(d,-@DaysToStart,@CurrentDate),101) -- getting DATE only
--
```

Comment: How do you end up with gems like `When @Diff = 0 Then 0 Else @Diff`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lStartDay = 5 will always give u Friday. you need to add 4 for Thursday

```
DECLARE @DaysToStart int
 SET @DaysToStart = (DatePart(dw,@CurrentDate) - @StartWeekDay)
 IF @DaysToStart <= .1 
  BEGIN
    SET @DaysToStart = @DaysToStart + 7 
  END
```

If you are declaring @DaysToStart and DatePart also returns INT, why the comparison with .1??

Comment: wouldnt the week always start with "Sunday"?  So... Thursday would be 5 right?

Comment: That portion doesn't matter... I've tried commenting it, and it still doesn't do anything... Basically I'm just trying to figure out how many days apart the current date are from the startweek.

Comment: see my new post, i executed for few days its always giving me Thursday of the week, might help!!

Comment: This actually was the answer.  In SQL the dates are 0-6 not 1-7.  So what happened was the start of week was always Friday, because 5 is Friday.  Your initial answer is 100% accurate.

Answer (score 4):

The following query is a standard way of rounding dates to the beginiing of the week.  That, however, is treated as a Monday...

```
DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, @YourDate), 0)
```

If you offset your values by 3, this will change the function to round down to the previous Thursday...

```
DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, @YourDate-3), 3)
```

**EDIT:** This should have been 3, not 4...

```
SET @yourDate    = getDate()
SET @firstDay    = 3
SET @RoundedDate = DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, @YourDate-@firstDay), @firstDay)

 Value of @firstDay | Day of week this will round to
--------------------+--------------------------------
        0           |        Monday
        1           |        Tuesday
        2           |        Wednesday
        3           |        Thursday
        4           |        Friday
        5           |        Saturday
        6           |        Sunday
```

Comment: Where are you suggesting this goes?

Comment: @Shmewnix - It can replace pretty much all of your logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
        DECLARE @StartWeekDay int 
    SET @StartWeekDay = 5

    DECLARE @CurrentDate DateTime 
    SET @CurrentDate = '8/24/2012'
    DECLARE @CurrentWeekDay int
    SET @CurrentWeekDay = DATEPART(dw,@CurrentDate)
    SELECT @CurrentWeekDay;

    DECLARE @Diff int
    SET @Diff = @StartWeekDay - @CurrentWeekDay

    SET @Diff = Case When @Diff > 0 Then -6 When @Diff = 0 Then 0 Else @Diff End

    --
     DECLARE @DaysToStart int
     SET @DaysToStart = (DatePart(dw,@CurrentDate) - @StartWeekDay)
--change here to <1 and not <=1 that will add 8 and return friday at the end
     IF @DaysToStart < 1 
      BEGIN
        SET @DaysToStart = @DaysToStart + 7 
      END
      SELECT @DaysToStart;
     DECLARE @myStartWeekDate DateTime
     --SET @myStartWeekDate = dbo.DateOnly(DATEADD(d,@Diff,@CurrentDate))
     SET @myStartWeekDate =  Convert(nvarchar,DateAdd(d,-@DaysToStart,@CurrentDate),101) 
     SELECT @myStartWeekDate
```

Comment: This sets the `@currentdate` to a defined date.  This stored procedures gets `@currentdate` as the date the report is run... (the parameter is passed through the program)

Comment: this is just the test , you can change it to GETDATE()